# How to evaluate $\int_0^\infty e^{-x^a}dx$

Tags: definite-integrals, exponential-function, gamma-function

please help me how to do it.I have no clue about how to begin.I attempted to replicate how the Gaussian integral is solved but that would require 'a' number of equations relating spherical and Cartesian co ordinates which I'm not even sure exist.Then I attempted  the substitution $x^a=t$ which yielded $\Gamma(2-1/a)=(1-1/a)!$ a result from the gamma function.
Is this correct? How do we find the value of the gamma function for fractional values?

Comment: This (substitution method, didn't verify answer) is correct. About the gamma function: you either get some special values and use identities or do numerics. See wikipedia

Comment: Did you forget the minus in front of the $x^a$?

Comment: In that case, the answer should be $\frac{1}{a}!$

Comment: oops i forgot about that, I have corrected it now thank you for your answer.

Comment: @padmabilgi If the answer helped you, don't forget to upvote and accept.

Comment: yea just upvoted

Answer (score 2):

The Gamma function is defined by
$$\Gamma(x) = \int_0^\infty t^{x-1}e^{-t}dt$$
and we have $\Gamma(x) = (x-1)!$. This can be written a bit simpler as
$$ x! = \int_0^\infty t^{x}e^{-t}dt$$ 
The approach you tried works. Substitute $t = x^a$, $dt = ax^{a-1}$ to get
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^\infty e^{-x^a} dx &= \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-t}}{ax^{a-1}}dt\\
&=\frac{1}{a}\int_0^\infty x^{1-a}e^{-t}dt\\
&=\frac{1}{a}\int_0^\infty t^{\frac{1}{a}-1}e^{-t}dt\\
&= \frac{1}{a}(\frac{1}{a}-1)!\\
&= \frac{1}{a}!
\end{aligned}
$$

In the last line I used the defining property of the factorial function $x! = x(x-1)!$.

For many values this has a closed form, but for most values it does not, take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Particular_values